# RowSource invalid for populating a Listbox with table data in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

I am trying to create a user form for data entry and want to display the user's entries into a table in a list box. I still have more code to complete but I am running into errors when trying to execute commands from a tutorial I am following (I am very green at VBA programing).

Pictured below is the code I have thus far:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim cbpart As Range
Dim cbdefect As Range
Dim cbaccept As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Pick Lists")

'Defining Combo Box Data (cbparttype)___________________________

For Each cbpart In ws.Range("Part_Type_List")
    With Me.cbparttype
        .AddItem cbpart.Value
    End With
Next cbpart

'Defining Combo Box Data (cbdefecttype)_________________________

For Each cbdefect In ws.Range("Defect_Type_List")
    With Me.cbdefecttype
        .AddItem cbdefect
    End With
Next cbdefect

'Defining Combo Box Data (cbacceptability)_______________________

For Each cbaccept In ws.Range("Accept_Condition")
    With Me.cbacceptability
        .AddItem cbaccept
    End With
Next cbaccept

Call Refresh_Data

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

'Setting Clear button Function _________________________________

cbparttype.Clear
cbdefecttype.Clear
cbacceptability.Clear
tbpnum.Value = ""
tbrev.Value = ""
tbloc.Value = ""
tbpic.Value = ""
tbprob.Value = ""
tbprog.Value = ""
tbnotes.Value = ""

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

'Setting the Save Button________________________________________

ThisWorkbook.Save
MsgBox "Data Saved"

End Sub

Sub Refresh_Data()

'Setting the table Window_______________________________________

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Primary Data")
Dim last_Row As Long
last_Row = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Range("A:A"))

With Me.lbdisplay
                .ColumnHeads = True
                .ColumnCount = 11
                .RowSource = "Primary Data!A1:K" & last_Row
                
End With

End Sub
```

My current user form is configured like so:

[image]

The error I keep getting when running the code is Run-time error '380': Could not set the RowSource property. Invalid property value.

I think it has to do with the line: .RowSource = "Primary Data!A1:K" & last_Row, but for the life of me I cannot figure out what I am referencing or configuring wrong. the worksheet that is storing the data is called "Primary Data" and the cells are not formulated into a table. see below:

[image]

any suggestions?

Comment: You should have `.RowSource = "'Primary Data'!A1:K"`,  since sheet name contains space(s)

Comment: I tried that and I am still getting errors telling me an Invalid property value. would there be any value in formatting the data as a table and referencing the table's range?